# how to transfer website from testsite to root folder Joomla2.5 & virtuemart 2.06

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

i just moved my testsite to root folder.. my problem is am getting the home page of my site, when i click some other menu or links in my site.. it is again displaying my home page but the url is changing according to the link.. need help...

Joomla 2.5
Virtuemart 2.6

Answer (score 0):

Are you using sef components installed in your joomla extensions if so disable the sef configurations and check ,if it works then it is a sef configuration issue you have to work on that

You can also use akeeba to take backup from testsite and move that to root by using kickstart